# Why Microsoft Windows Phone 7 Team didn't use the same semantics of ActiveControl for Winform?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, windows-phone-7

On Windows Phone 7 to get the current control one would use

```
FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()
```

Wherea on Winform it is just ActiveControl.

Why use 2 semantics which is a nuisance for portability ? Is there any difference of behavior you can see between the two ? If yes that makes sense, otherwise that doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

the WP7 api does not stem from Winforms, but from WPF and Silverlight. The question should therefore be why does WPF use GetFocusedElement.

The answer is pretty simple: It was judged more adequate than ActiveControl. What does ActiveControl mean? The active control is the control which has focus. GetFocusedElement seams better to me.

Comment: But hard to remember FocusManager whereas ActiveControl is in default System.Windows.Forms namespace

Answer (score 1):

Development for WP7 as a whole is similar to Desktop-based WPF development. Seeing as MS is keeping WPF to WinPhone7 namespaces consistent, it actually makes sense in a way.

Comment: Guess it always makes sense in some way :) but then instead of windows 7 I could have replaced the question with WPF.

Comment: I think the whole point is getting more clear on what exactly the state of the control is. Active only means "can be interacted with", whereas focused is a well-defined description. It always depends on viewpoint, and it might be a nuisance if you're used to the Forms Namespace, but if you just happen to start programming for Windows, it's actually less confusing.